# SXA site not detected on content delivery - url goes to default home

Tags: sxa, multisite

On our Content Delivery server, the published URL is redirecting to the default home page of Sitecore and I need it to redirect to the SXA site home.

Are there specific steps I should take?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but is SXA installed on your CD?

Comment: Any update? I'm facing the exactly same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site definition (.../Settings/Site Grouping/[Site name]) contains (amongst others) the url of your site in the `Host Name` field - a parameter you will normally find in the sites definition of a Sitecore site. When your url maps on a wrong site, this setting is probably wrong. Note that you can use wildcards and pipes in this field (just as you would in a non-sxa host name setting).

You can also use the SXA site manager to verify the settings in a multi-site environment: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/getting_started_with_sxa/tenants_and_sites/manage_multiple_sites_with_the_sxa_site_manager
With the SXA site manager you can also change the order of the sites to fix hostname issues.

Comment: I am adding "*" in host name in  (.../Settings/Site Grouping/[Site name]) but still content delivery server not redirecting to SXA site

Comment: Check my comment on the question.. and verify SXA site manager. And make sure everything is published..

Answer (score 0):

I tried above approach plus clearing cache but didn't help.

Finally, I renamed the SiteName in the node and field and then publish, and it starts appearing correct website.